# Dalvid opcode parser

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex, capstone

I'm reverse engineering some Dalvik obfuscator, of android applications.
After the de-obfuscation, I have the correct bytecode that should be executed by the Dalvik machine, however I'm not sure how I can parse it for static reverse engineering. I know there are solutions such as [JEB](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/), and there is an opensource solution such as [JADX](https://github.com/skylot/jadx), However I'm looking for something which feels more like:
[Capstone dissassembler](https://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_python.html), which can take assembly bytecode, and translate it to opcodes. I want the same thing with Dalvik byte code, and I was hoping a solution could come from here.

The problem with JADX is that it needs to parse the whole DEX file, and it cant just take the byte code. I understand it might be awkward, as some opcodes require strings by IDs (which are only available through parsing the DEX file), but I am looking for a more generic solution where I could see the dalvik code, with perhaps missing parts like `<String ID:0xAA>`

I wouldn't mind also patching the opensource code to achieve what I want, but the sources feel a bit complicated, so any tips will be appreicated

Comment: Have you checked smali's dexlib2? You probably can customize the [DexBackedInstruction#readFrom](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/dexbacked/instruction/DexBackedInstruction.java#L60) to your needs.